# How to clone typed/typing values from input box and mask it as asterix (*) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i clone the typed/typing values from input text box and fake the values into asterix (*).

Scenario 1: http://jsfiddle.net/cs92h03s/ (when initially loading)

```
<input type="text" class="input" />
<span class="input-close"></span>
```

Scenario 2: http://jsfiddle.net/cs92h03s/1 When started to enter values on input.

```
<input type="text" class="input" value="abcd" />
<span class="input-close">****</span>
```

Please help!

Comment: can you use angular js??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, this works on paste and delete also:

```
<input type="text" class="input"/>
<span class="input-close"></span>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.input').on("input propertychange",function() {
        var s = '';
        for (var i=0; i<$('.input').val().length; i++) {
            s += '*';
        }
        $('.input-close').html(s);
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cs92h03s/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Jquery .keypress functionality to check if something is typed and .append to append to your * to span for each typed key:

```
$( ".input" ).keypress(function() {
  $(".input-close").append('*');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I delete a character, or use mouse to paste something into it.

Comment: It doesn't as it's not mentioned in OP as problem